Swing JComboBox showing a graphic instead of text
I am upgrading a Java project from Java 8 to Java 11.  One applet uses SwingX 1.6.3; the Swing version is not being changed at this time.
The applet UI has a Swing JComboBox that gets dynamically populated.  When the user selects a music file, the combo box loads the rest of the tracks from the appropriate album.  The combo box uses a custom renderer that extends DefaultListCellRenderer to show the track titles in its list.
In Java 8, this control properly renders the text tiles of the tracks.  The applet uses Jide 3.5.6 LookAndFeelFactory with XERTO_STYLE.
In Java 11, this control displays a few musical notes, that bear no resemblance to the music.  The applet uses Jide 3.7.15 VSNET_STYLE.  The list cell renderer has not been changed.  I have not found any graphical resource that resembles musical notes.  It seems the renderer is displaying an icon (from an unknown source) instead of the desired string.
I've traced through the custom renderer and determined it is setting the correct track titles and passing these to a call to the javax.swing.ListCellRenderer method getListCellRendererComponent.  I believe nothing else going into this call has changed.
So why would the displayed component switch from text to a graphic, and how do I switch it back?
Edit 1:  I dumped the Component object being returned from the renderer.  I observe that no icon or other graphic has been specified.
When nothing is selected:
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer$UIResource[,-77,-19,0x0,invalid,
alignmentX=0.0,AlignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@1672b5a8,flags=25165832,
maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,
horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,
text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]

When a track is selected, eg. "Title Of the Song", the only difference is the content of the attribute text:
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer$UIResource[,-77,-19,0x0,invalid,
alignmentX=0.0,AlignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@1672b5a8,flags=25165832,
maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,
horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,
text=Title Of the Song,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]

Edit 2:
I found an interesting observation, hopefully it's relevant.  The property preferredSize is null, but the command bar containing this combo box has this block in its buildContent() method:
trackCombo = new JComboBox();
trackCombo.setPreferredSize(COMBO_PREFERRED_SIZE);
trackCombo.setRenderer(new TrackListCellRenderer(trackCombo.getRenderer()));
trackCombo.setAction(ActionFactory.createAction(ActionKey.TRACK_CHANGE));
trackCombo.setFont(FONT);
...
JPanel trackBox = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
trackBox.add(trackCombo);
...
add(trackBox);

Where COMBO_PREFERRED_SIZE has previously been set in the command bar class:
private static final Dimension COMBO_PREFERRED_SIZE = new Dimension(100, 26);


You are setting the preferred size of the combobox, not the renderer. So it is expected that the renderer’s preferred size is null.
